# Adding to a JSON file with jQuery getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

at the moment I have a HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $.getJSON('data.json', { "firstName":"Matt", "lastName":"Jam", "joined": { "month":"July", "day":12, "year":2012 },  function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.users) {
            output+="<li>" + data.users[i].firstName + " " + data.users[i].lastName + "--" + data.users[i].joined.month+"</li>";
        }

        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
  });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and a data.json file:

```
{"users":[
        {
            "firstName":"Ray",
            "lastName":"Villalobos",
            "joined": {
                "month":"January",
                "day":12,
                "year":2012
            }
        },
        {
            "firstName":"John",
            "lastName":"Jones",
            "joined": {
                "month":"April",
                "day":28,
                "year":2010
            }
        }
]}
```

My question is- what would I have to add to the JSON file to return the infomation that i'm passing  via the jquery getJSON function? (`"firstName":"Matt", "lastName":"Jam", "joined": { "month":"July", "day":12, "year":2012 },`)

Comment: You can't do this client-side, you need to use server-side technology

Comment: Why do you need to send it back to the client? You already have it. Just store it in a variable on the client side before sending, and append it to `data.users`.  `data.users.push(theUserObject)`

Comment: Or do you need it to persist in the JSON? (for which you need a server-side solution)

Comment: its a test to see if i can do it, eventually I will be passing variables. I have the server side technology to read the JSON file without passing the infomation, is that not enough?

Comment: I would just love to know how to store that infomation in the JSON file

Comment: to put it another way, i'm investigating how to store data in JSON files

Comment: You can write JSON notation in a Javascript file. Then when you call this file, the string can be converted to a JSON object. You can alternatively return a JSON notation string from your server side response and have it converted on the client side.

Comment: ah Ok, fair enough. What got me thinking was the very last example on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ were they are passing infomation as well as returning. thanks